# OnKey "Delete" clear combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a userform with multiple comboboxes. User can type in a new item or pick one from the list.

He can start typing first letters of wanted item but when he makes a mistake and starts with e.g. "b" instead of "n" he has to clear the combobox manually or find the item on the list using mouse or arrows.

I would like to quickly clear the box using the delete key so the user can start typing again. But I don't know where to put this line of code if correct (enter event, change event, some other maybe?).

```
Application.OnKey "{Delete}", "WyczyscPole"
```

First Excel needs to know which box the user is in, and then clear it.

I tried to create separate module with a variable that finds out the current combobox name and clear it in next step. But I don't know whether called sub below is even correct.

```
Sub WyczyscPole()

Dim NazwaPola As ComboBox

NazwaPola = frmZakupy.ActiveControl.Name
NazwaPola.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the KeyDown event to capture the Delete key (KeyCode = 46) when the user is in the combobox.

```
Private Sub NazwaPola_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = 46 Then
        Me.NazwaPola.Value = vbNullString
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Can you please tell me why you used KeyDown event ? Shoudn't it be KeyPress ? Would it make a difference ?

Comment: I don't know why, but KeyPress does not capture keys like Delete and Backspace, so you have to use KeyDown (or KeyUp).

Answer (score 0):

Please try: `frmZakupy.value=''`

It's a good practice to don't use special characters like 'ś','ć' in any names.